# Удалить большой файл из git

Tags: github, git-filter-branch, git-rm

Добавил большой файл в коммит, github отказался его принимать:

```
remote: error: File system/storage/logs/error.log is 182.48 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Применил:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f /system/storage/logs/error.log' HEAD
```

Но получаю:

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

Соответственно следующий

```
git push
```

Возвращает к первому шагу.

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

Показывает, что этого файла уже нет в коммите.
Очистка файла error.log также не помогает решить проблему.

Comment: у вас неправильный путь уберите слэш в начале `'rm -f system/storage/logs/error.log'`

Comment: Спасибо! Был невнимателен, вопрос снят.